# iOS - UITableView add single static cell to dynamic table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I Have a `UITableView` which is controlled by `NSFetchedResultsController`. I want to add single cell to the first row and make this cell static. In other words, there will be a button which will open another View Controller.

Until now, I was ok with fetched results controller and table. Now I'm a bit confused. How should I do this?

Instead using a header might be ok too, but I don't want this header to be on top all the time. I want this cell to be just like `WhatsApp` iOS "`Create new group`" cell on chats panel.

Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way of doing this is Goto UITableView -> Drag a UIView onto it above your regular cell as Header View, add button on it and action in the ViewController, it will be always on top no need to write any code to handle this.

Comment: Instead of creating a cell you should add a button on in table view's header.

Comment: Adding a view is the best one! Thank you @iphonic I don't know why i did not think this. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create tableview with number of rows fetched from NSFetchedResultsController +1. Also in `cellForRowIndex` method you will need to add a check like `indexPath.row == 0` and in there you will make the changes.

Also you will have to add action for that button within that section. You can also set different custom `tableview` for first row.
It can be similar to following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  if(indexPath.row==0){
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellWithButton", for: indexPath) as! CellWithButton
  }
  else{
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OtherCells", for: indexPath) as! OtherCells
      //here add data for cells from your array
   }  
 return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataArray = ["A","B","C"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataArray.count+1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CreateNewGroupCell") as! CreateNewGroupCell
        return cell
    }
    else
    {
       // Get the data from Array
          let data = self.dataArray[indexPath.row-1]

       // Logic to show other cells
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OtherCell") as! OtherCell
          return cell

       // ....
    }

}
```